# jQuery build <li> using object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to build a list with li's from an object

The problem is I'm trying to give them a data-attribute with the name of the key in the object. But I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

This is the object ( and the result of the console.log in the last screenshot )

[image]

And this is the desired result

[image]

This is my code so far, I'm trying using nested $.each loops but it's not giving the desired results. Think i'm close but slightly on the wrong path

```
function getQuestions(categories){
    var o = new Object;
    $.getJSON('../data/data.js', function(data){
        $.each(categories, function(index, val){
            o[val]= data[val];
        });
        console.log(o);
    });
};
```

thank you!

Comment: Is your Object o filled out like you wish it to be? If not then how would you like it to be filled out? if the Object is correct what's holding you back from generating the li's? ( Your general question is unclear when I read your post )

Comment: The object is filled out like i want it! but i can't seem to translate it into the li's that hold the data-category of the array names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo full jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/d4d9L9ah/

HTML:

```
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
//Object O correct example
var o = new Object();
o['test1'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
o['test2'] = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff'];
o['test3'] = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'];

//checking to see if it's the correctly built
console.log(o);

//using jquery
$.each(o, function(a, b){
    $.each(b, function(c, d){
        $('#container').append('<li data-category="' + a + '">' + d + '</li>');
    });
});
```

I had to rebuild your Object o to test. You only need the double loop at the end.

[image]

Comment: Aha this is working. I didn't know you could use the variables from a parent $.each in a nested $.each. Thank you!

Comment: You can if it is some sort of array. No problem. GL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = { category_1: { 0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three' }, category_2: { 0: 'four', 1: 'five', 2: 'six' }}

for( var category in obj ) {

    $.each( obj[ category ], function( i, el ) {

        console.log( '<li data-category="' + category + '">' + el + '</li>' );

    } );

}
```

Comment: if you use each why you use for ?

Comment: because we're iterating through an object, not an array. if you wanted to do the same thing using `$.each`, you will have to convert the object to an array first.

Comment: yes, but calling `$( obj ).each()` will return only the child object, without the key name. see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/1v5r5nsn/

( sorry for multiple edits - I couldn't figure out how to paste code inside the comment)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this:

```
var $list = $("<ul id='question-form' class='list'>");

var json = {
  afwerken:["one","two"],
  communicatie:["one","two"],
};

$.each(json,function(_idx, _value){

   var liList = $.map(_value,function(_name){
    var li = $("<li>");
    li.attr("data-category",_idx);
    li.text(_name);
    return li
  })

  //I think this could be done nicer, without building an extra loop?
  $.each(liList,function(_idx, _li){
     $list.append(_li)
 });

});
console.log($list)
```